# Using array functions on mysql field

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a little strange question on MySql. I have table named adds and that table has places field where are stored places id. Places field value equals serialized array (e.t.c array('1', '3', '4')) of places ids'. Also i have search form and I would like to search more fields than one at once.
For ex: I would like find places with ID('3', '6', '8' and so on).
When i query using mysql like this it throws an error.

```
$val=array('3', '6', '8');
mysql_query("Select * from add where active='active' && array_intersect(unserialize(places))");
```

How can i do query? May it possible using stored procedures or functions in MySql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `implode` to turn it into a usable string. This assumes your array of values is completely trustworthy (i.e. not from a user submitted form)

```
$val=array('3', '6', '8');
mysql_query("Select * from add where active='active' AND ID IN (" . implode(',', $val) . ")";
```

Please be aware that [mysql_ functions have been removed from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: No, what i want isn't that. Here the value of ID is serialized array. Suppose that id isn't single number, here ID is serialized array. I must choose if some of $val array indexes exists in ID

Comment: Thank you very much